# Why my empty string assignment doesn't clear my string

Tags: c++

I have an exercise which looks like that:

> Problem statement is simple and straight forward . You will be given a non-negative integer P of length N and you need to check whether
> it's divisible by Q ?
>
> Integer P will be given in its decimal representation with P0 as leftmost digit and P1 as second digit from left !
>
> Rest of the digit can be generated from the formula :
>
> Pi = ( 4*Pi-1 + Pi-2 ) modulo Q for 2 <= i <= N-1
>
> Input
> The first line contains one integer T - denoting the number of test cases.
>
> T lines follow each containing four integers P0 , P1 , Q and N !
>
> Output
> For each testcase output YES if the corresponding integer is divisible by Q and NO otherwise.
>
> Constraints
> T <= 100000
> 0 < P0 , P1 , Q < 10
> 0 < N <= 1018
> Example
> Input:
>
> 4
>
> 1 4 2 2
>
> 1 4 2 1
>
> 4 2 3 2
>
> 3 4 7 3
>
> Output:
> YES
> NO
> YES
> NO
> Explanation
> Value of P is 14, 1, 42, 345 in respective cases !

and that's what I came up with

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int t, q, n, p_0, p_1, p_temp, p;
        vector<int> digits;
        vector<string> answers;
        string number = "";
    
        cin >> t;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
        {
            cin >> p_0 >> p_1 >> q >> n;
            if (n == 1)
            {
                digits.push_back(p_0);
            }
            else
            {
                digits.push_back(p_0);
                digits.push_back(p_1);
                for (int i = 2; i <= (n - 1); i++)
                {
                    p_temp = (4 * digits[i - 1] + digits[i - 2]) % q;
                    digits.push_back(p_temp);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < digits.size(); i++)
            {
                number += to_string(digits[i]);
            }
            p = stoi(number);
            cout << number << endl;
            if (p % q == 0)
            {
                answers.push_back("YES");
            }
            else
            {
                answers.push_back("NO");
            }
            number = "";
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << answers[i] << endl;
        }
    
    }
```

Everything I have done works fine, except for one thing, this part does not clear my `number` variable

```
    number = "";
```

And honestly I don't know why, could someone correct my mistakes and explain me what did I do wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Since `number` is `std::string`, you can try calling `number.clear()`

Comment: Doesn't work :/

Comment: It assigns empty string to your `number`. How do you check that "it does not clear it"? You always `std::cout` the content after the digits conversion and before the clear.

Comment: You could have moved `vector<int> digits;` and `string number = "";` to right inside the first for loop to have these cleared on each iteration.

Comment: @pptaszni raises a good point. If you don't have access to a debugger where you can step through the code 1 line at a time and look at the variables at each step, printing the values before and after something happens can be very helpful.

Comment: Even after correcting your bug, this method will not be able to handle numbers with up to 1018 digits. You don't need to use strings in practice here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with the digits vector.

Each loop the number string just gets repopulated with the digits vector which is never cleared.

Use digits.clear() to empty the vector like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    int t, q, n, p_0, p_1, p_temp, p;
    vector<int> digits;
    vector<string> answers;
    string number = "";

    cin >> t;

    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        cin >> p_0 >> p_1 >> q >> n;

        

        if (n == 1)
        {
            digits.push_back(p_0);
        }
        else
        {
            digits.push_back(p_0);
            digits.push_back(p_1);
            for (int i = 2; i <= (n - 1); i++)
            {
                p_temp = (4 * digits[i - 1] + digits[i - 2]) % q;
                digits.push_back(p_temp);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < digits.size(); i++)
        {
            number += to_string(digits[i]);
        }

        p = stoi(number);
        cout << number << endl;

        if (p % q == 0)
        {
            answers.push_back("YES");
        }
        else
        {
            answers.push_back("NO");
        }

        digits.clear();
        number = "";
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < answers.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << answers[i] << endl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To clear a string you can/should use `std::string::clear()` as:

```
number.clear();
```

There may be other **logical errors** in your program which may be the reason for not getting the output you expect.

Also instead of creating/initializing the string `number` using `string number = "";`, you should use

```
string number;//no need to write = ""
```

Comment: I tried this and Unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: It does clear the string otherwise the implementation of the standard library that you are using is broken. More likely your code has a bug and you need to use a debugger to step through the code line by line to see where its behavior deviates from your expectation.

Comment: Honestly I don't see how this answer is supposed to help, as empty string assignment has almost the same effect as calling `clear` (let's forget memory alloc/dealloc impl details). OP obviously has a logical error in his algorithm.

Comment: @pptaszni As i said there may be other **logical errors** (which is completely OP's responsibility to solve) in OP's program. I just mentioned standard ways to initialized the string and clearing the string.